# How do I fix Gnome after update?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, upgrade

I upgraded my Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04 using the little pop-up "DO YOU WANT TO UPGRADE?" box, but now when I log into my Gnome desktop, the desktop files load (drives/random picture/etc) but the actual GUI doesn't load.

There's not menu bar/tray etc

The hotkeys for switching desktops still work, CRTL + ALT + F1 works, and I can create shortcuts - but that's it.

Anyone know how to fix it?

I installed KDE as a backup awhile back, but I really would prefer to have GNOME back :/

Comment: Just a guess, might be a difference in handling some gconf options.

Comment: Just for reference are you logging in now under Ubuntu Classic or under the Unity interface?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to reset your GNOME configuration - if you're using Unity, [look at this post,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration) otherwise look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults).

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy, that's a messy one... I had this issue too. It looks like you have gnome3 ppa, but 11.04 is still gnome2 and gnome3 is kinda not-ready-yet (major issues with rendering on some graphic cards and badly generated default settings)  for 11.04 on some systems. Go back to gnome2 (remove gnome3 ppa and bring back `ubuntu-desktop` package would be the shortest way to do it). If you still have some problems it's probably gnome2 settings are broken.

My fix for this is:

Logout, switch to command line (`alt+ctrl+f1`), login.

in your /home/ backup those dirs and then remove them (just `mv` them somewhere):

`.gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity`

Switch back to X (`alt+ctrl+f7`), cry over your lost settings, try to restore them if you have some time to compare default and backup you made in the previous step.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation with some wrong compiz settings; try logging from another user, if it helps, you can reset some settings from main profile too.

Comment: OP here, turns out the GNOME3 session package didn't DL properly during upgrade, so I'm busy trying to install it - unfortunately I'm having issues with Synaptic Package Manager <broken packages>